# Testing Typescript classes within namespace using Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have the following method within a namespace:

```js
// main.ts
namespace testControl {

    export const isInternalLink = (link: string) => {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and following jest spec:

```js
// main.spec.ts

test('should return false given external link', () => {

 // How to use testControl.isInternalLink here ?

});
```

Tried adding

```
/// <reference path="./main.ts"/>
```

Tried wrapping the test within the same namespace

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the namespace itself:

```
// main.ts
export namespace testControl {

    export const isInternalLink = (link: string) => {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then import the namespace in your spec:

```
// main.spec.ts
import { testControl } from './main'

test('should return false given external link', () => {

  // How to use testControl.isInternalLink here ?
  expect(testControl.isExternalLink('')).toBe(false)
});
```